# How to load each url off a sitemap and scrape more data

Tags: python, json, sitemap, scrape

i'm trying to load all the links found on the sitemap of the certain site and then load all of those links and grab more data (stock, sizes and their ID). So far the code finds all of the links, converts them to .json but when it goes to load each site and scrape more data it only does it to the vary last link in the sitemap. I need it to do it to all of the links in the sitemap. If anyone could please help me with this that would be awesome!

Thanks :)

```
def check_endpoint():
    url = 'https://shopnicekicks.com/sitemap_products_1.xml'
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'lxml')
    for url in soup.find_all('loc'): #load the url and find all product links.
        produrl = url.text
        UrlDB.append(produrl)
        endpoint = produrl + '.json' #take a product links and convert to .json
        JsonUrl = endpoint 

    #load each product link and find variants.
    req = requests.get(JsonUrl)
    reqJson = json.loads(req.text) 
    CartLink = JsonUrl.split("/")[2]    
    CartLink = "https://{}".format(CartLink)

    for product in reqJson['product']['variants']:
        Variants = product['id']
        Size = product['title']
        Price = product['price']                   
        Stock = product['inventory_quantity']
        atclink = "Size = {}, Stock = {}, Link = {}, /cart/{}:1 ".format(Size, Stock, CartLink, Variants)
        print (atclink) #print all variants 


return
```

Comment: tldr: I need to above code to print all variants for all links in the sitemap but its only doing it to the last link in the sitemap. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See that comment in the middle of your example?  Indent that comment and everything after it 4 spaces.

Comment: I tried that and it throws an error. `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: Add "print(JsonUrl)" just before you get the URL, then use your browser to see what's served at that URL.  (I will bet it's not JSON)

Comment: Here is one of the URLS that is printed https://shopnicekicks.com/products/vans-skool-reissue-ca-leather-wool-biking-red-black.json

Im pretty sure thats a json url

Comment: Hi chris. No there is no error but it is the last URL that it is only getting the info for.